# How to insert a value from DLookup into a table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Ive created a DLookup to search for the table ([Copy of tblTypeOfAsset]) record i have just added from combo boxes to find the ID. From here i want to insert this value into another table, just to test that its working. Beneath is the code ive tried to use.

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Copy Of tblTypeOfAsset](Manufacturer, Model, Version, CalInterval) Values ('" & Me.CBOFirm & "','" & Me.CBOComms & "' , '" & Me.CBOSpSettings & "','" & Me.CBOConfigP & "');"

Dim varx As Variant



varx = DLookup("TypeID", "[Copy Of tblTypeOfAsset]", "[Manufacturer] = Forms![JA_Data_Input_Info]!CBOFirm And [Model] = Forms![JA_Data_Input_Info]!CBOComms And [Version] = Forms![JA_Data_Input_Info]!CBOSpSettings")

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO 1test (test) VALUES ('varx')"



End Sub
```

this code inserts a sting 'varx' and not the ID value, without the commas i get a "runtime error: '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Concatenate* the value and the SQL:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO 1test (test) VALUES ('" & varx & "')"
```